# How do I change the 'Document Mode' of Internet Explorer in web.config?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, web-config

How do i change the 'Document Mode' of IE in web config?

I have developed a website and it works good in my local. But after publishing, when am trying to open the site i could see some misalignment.i checked the document mode using developer tool it is IE7 standards.

When i change it in to IE9 there it works as expected.

Comment: You can use the `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">` meta tag in your master page or page. [See this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6771258).

Comment: I added below code in we config <system.webServer>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <clear />
        <add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=EmulateIE9" />
       </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
  </system.webServer> but still this issue is there

Comment: You need to have it as an **HTML** header. What you did is to add an **HTTP** header, this is something different.

Comment: But i got this solution from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj676913%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: OK, seems it is possible to use it as HTTP header, too. I've never tried, I've only worked with HTML headers successfully.

Comment: @UweKeim - The meta tag is unreliable because often the mode is selected already before the browser renders the tag.  Using the header is the preferred method, and always has been.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use Emulate-IE9, just use `<add name="X-UA-Compatible" value="IE=edge" />`  This will cause IE to always render in its most standards compliant mode.

However, your problem is most likely not this header.  It's probably that you are not using a proper doctype tag, or you are doing something else to force IE into compatibility mode.  The X-UA-Compatible header will not fix a basic problem with your HTML validity that causes compatibility mode.

Another possibility is if you are on a corporate network and they are overriding the compatibility mode for your site (usually because they are trying to make older apps on the same site work).  In which case, you will need to talk to your network administrators to fix the problem.